# Apache: Add custom tmp-Dir for every vhost

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, bash

I need to change the existing vhost-configuration files. My goal is to add an custom `tmp-path` to every host-config, that is stored at `/configs`.

Maybe it would be possible to include an additional config-file in every vHost-config, that allows to set this globally with some kind of `placeholder`?

Something like

```
include /configs/_additional.values
```

in every vHost-config and something like

```
upload_tmp_dir /var/www/vhosts/$username/.tmp
```

in this additional config.

Maybe you out there got an idea?